# Cannot create a folder in a container in Azure through the UI

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I get this error when I try to add a new directory to an existing container in a storage account. I have "hierarchical namespace" enabled against the storage account.

[image]

I notice that I also see this error when I try to navigate to "Manage ACL". Perhaps it is related?

[image]

If I try to add the same directory via Azure Storage Explorer then I get a very long error message containing " reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ". Again I have no idea what this is.

What do I need to do in order to add a new directory?

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer my own question, I deleted and re-created the storage account. Now adding a directory is fine. The storage account with the problem was created by someone else and then modified by me - perhaps that caused a problem somewhere? The re-created account was only created by me. That was the only difference between them (as far as I can tell!).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but since it was likely created by someone else it was probably an access policy violation. You can add your own access policies depending on your level of access to your own organizations hierarchy. When you created the other one it likely set you as owner/contributor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).